# Getting the testrun ID after creating a test run in Testrail

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testrail

I am trying to implement testrail integration using Testrail's API endpoint with Selenium C#.  I have successfully created a test run.  Now I want to get the test run ID that was just created.  How can this be done?

Here is my code for creating the test run:

```
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public async Task OneTimeSetUp()
        {
            RestRequest newRequest = new RestRequest($"index.php?/api/v2/add_run/{project_id}", Method.Post);
            string authInfo = Base64StringConverter.GetBase64String("email:password");
            newRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
            newRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            //reading json content
            string jsonFromFile;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(_createrunpath))
            {
                jsonFromFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var customerFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateRun>(jsonFromFile);
            newRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            newRequest.AddJsonBody(customerFromJson);

            //act
            var newResponse = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(newRequest);
            HttpStatusCode statusCode = newResponse.StatusCode;

            //assert
            Console.WriteLine((int)statusCode);
            Assert.That((int)statusCode, Is.EqualTo(200));
        }
```

JSON File

```
{
  "assignedto_id": 1,
  "suite_id": 1111,
  "name": "This is a new test run test",
  "refs": "API Auto Tests",
  "description": "This is a description of the test"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://support.gurock.com/hc/en-us/articles/7077874763156-Runs#addrun) says that `add_run` method returns the same response as `get_run`, so you should be able to get the ID of the newly created run by fetching it from the `id` field of the resulting JSON